# How to use hints of Android Studio correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I work with android studio it shows hints very often, I have 2 questions about it:
[image]
1)  Why do android studio when I press enter (in scenario like on screenshot) makes just

```
noteRef.get()
.addOnSuccessListener {}

}
```

instead of

```
noteRef.get()
.addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->  }

}
```

Is there a way generate { documentSnapshot ->  } automatically?

2) Second problem: imagine, I have code like this:

```
    var planetMarsSize = 0
    var planetEarthSize=0
    planetMarsSize = 5
```

for example I made mistake in this code and have to make "planetEarthSize = 5" instead of "planetMarsSize = 5" so i place cursor between "Mars" and "size", delete "Mars" and start tipping "Earth" - in this case Android studio shows me a hint to autocomplete text, I press enter. At the end text become "planetEarthSizeSize = 5" so android studio shows error. How can I make android studio to autocomplete "planetEarthSize" instead of "planetEarthSizeSize"?
Video of problem: https://photos.app.goo.gl/qAbcxtZsV4URwWwR8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The only difference between the two methods is that in the second, you can choose the name of the parameter. In the first one, you can access the parameter with `it`

2) You can press TAB on your keyboard to overwrite the whole variable name (it actually says this in the little dialog that pops up :) )